# Find text match between two start and end parameters

Tags: regex, string, text

I would like to know if there is a more optimal or the most efficient literal to match all variants to find all the conicidences of a text, passing two params (start, end), regardless of the internal characters.

**REGEX** `(color[^$]*blue)`

```
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. color Dolores ducimus nulla doloribus quod odit modi perspiciatis delectus earum nisi, sit ex! blue Doloribus dolores provident hic consequuntur natus ipsa inventore expedita!
Fugit autem saepe fuga maiores quo optio exercitationem reiciendis COLOR deleniti iure ipsam beatae nostrum vel dolore dolorum id esse inventore eligendi velit ut temporibus eius in, BLUE corrupti laboriosam modi. Excepturi.
Iure maiores, fuga neque vitae est repellendus colorpraesentium accusamus, magnam nesciunt cumque fugiat nonblue impedit! Laborum exercitationem architecto fugiat libero eaque provident voluptatem aperiam unde nulla impedit porro, itaque nisi.
```

**Expected result**

1. `color Dolores ducimus nulla doloribus quod odit modi perspiciatis delectus earum nisi, sit ex! blue`
2. `COLOR deleniti iure ipsam beatae nostrum vel dolore dolorum id esse inventore eligendi velit ut temporibus eius in, BLUE`
3. `colorpraesentium accusamus, magnam nesciunt cumque fugiat nonblue`

Comment: What about just using `color.*?blue`? Not sure what you're trying to do with `[^$]*` - but that character class matches any character except `$` literally (not end of line anchor); for end of line anchor just use `.` since it doesn't match newline characters anyway?

Comment: `\b(?:color(?:\W+\w+){1,3}?\W+blue|blue(?:\W+\w+){1,3}?\W+cikir)\b` matches `color` followed by one to 3 other words followed by `blue` or `blue` followed by one to three words followed by `color`. If that isn't what you're asking, it may get you started.

Comment: @ctwheels its great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches all between color and blue (included) with no color or blue in between:

```
(?i)color(?:(?!color|blue).)*blue
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iAjFmg/2)

Answer (score 1):

If the expected result is what you want, this is should be your solution:
https://regexr.com/4rjt3

The flag "i", will make the regex not case sensitive.

Please notice - I replaced `[^$]` with `(.*)` so you will get the results separately.